What wood finishes stand up to machine washing
I'm making some oversize wood buttons from North American hardwoods such as hickory, oak and cedar elm to be attached to washable cotton material bags.  These bags are expected to be regularly washed in a washing machine but not machine dried.  What finishes would provide adequate protection?  The button attachment is to be through holes in the buttons which means it's also important that the finish be in the holes (~3/16 inch) which probably means the finish would have to be sprayed to insure coverage within the holes.


What finishes would provide adequate protection?

I don't think there is one.
I don't believe there's any wood finish that can be guaranteed to withstand repeated wash cycles (chemical attack plus abrasion) in concert with the other factors in this use-case — abrasion from day-to-day use plus knocks and scrapes, and once (not IF) damage gets through to the wood that's the beginning of the end for the finish.
The strongest finishes there are — this includes true 2K finishes, certain epoxies, catalysed lacquers, two-pack varnishes — can be one or several orders of magnitude stronger/more durable than anything we typical see at a hobby or leisure-woodworking level (ditto most YouTube woodworking for a mass audience BTW). But even these will struggle because of one key element here: the coat thickness.
In short, thin finishes are by their very nature minimally protective1.
Even these strong finishes require a minimum coat thickness and this is, well, it's not thin. So even if you wanted to try with one of these costly finishes, for full protection you'd need to apply quite a lot. The result being the buttons will look essentially like they're encased in plastic.

So, barring the option of simply going with bare wood2, possibly the best bet here could be resin impregnation.
The first downside to this is the buttons will look less like wood (zero physical texture, although the grain/figure patterns remain) and certainly will no longer feel like wood because the final material is as much the hard resin as it is the original wood.
Plus number one, this means you don't necessarily have to use the strongest and most durable woods to begin with. This might be of some benefit to you on the making end and expands the horizons of what wood species can be used.
Plus number two, it opens up the possibility of colouring the wood any hue you wish.
A further downside, and this might be the biggie, is cost. While you can do resin impregnation at various price points, even at the lower-cost end the entire setup — a safe vacuum chamber and its associated equipment, the resin itself, and the heating setup — is not exactly cheap. So without the expectation of offsetting this cost over numerous projects over time it may not be an expense you can stomach.

1 You might want to look into the newest kid on the block, nano finishes, as an option. I don't hold out much hope they'd do enough over the expected lifespan (with no upkeep/topup possible) but talk to the manufacturers, see what they have to say.
2 This isn't as crazy as it sounds. Consider for example that commercial wooden coat buttons and toggles can survive not just years but decades after whatever finish was used (wax?) has long worn away. However, these are not typically washed often IME, so the analogy is not perfect.
